# Documentation headers for Linq to SQL entities

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm getting to grips with a project that uses Linq to SQL. I would like to add documentation headers to members of some of the entities managed by Linq to SQL but I'm aware that partial classes where most of the members are defined are generated by a tool.

Since I don't want to add any code to these generated partial classes, is there any other way I can create documentation headers for the members defined in them?

Comment: what's the use of documentation headers in generated code? Everybody will know the use of the generated code anyway

Comment: Sorry to speak so plainly, but that is completely wrong. The generated code will correspond to entities in the domain model which have business meaning. The documentation headers are there to explain this business meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer is that there is no answer. You cannot add document headers except to the generated part of the code.

Comment: Therefore, run screaming from Linq to SQL and use something that supports POCOs instead. Which you should have done in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the linq-to-sql is your data layer for straighforward CRUD. You do not want straight linq2sql as your business layer  but let's not start that discussion.

If you really want to document them, you can extend the partial classes: create one for reach linq-2-sql entity and add your documentation there. Most likely you will anyway need to extend them with some additional business functionality if you intend to use them as business later.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AdventureWorks
{
partial class Address
{
   // some documentation here
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Ha! It is a good discussion for the pub. Thanks for your answer, I'll check it out.

Comment: I don't see how I can 'redeclare' members in my own part of the class in order to add a documentation header. As soon as I declare the member, I get a compiler error because of the duplicate member declaration.